# How to use loop inside if statement

Tags: java

```
HasbroIssuanceDateData data1 = extractedDateData.get(c);

if (data.getOpeningBankReference().equals(data1.getOpeningBankReference())) {
    data1.getOpeninbankRefernce();
    data1.getPoNumber()).concat(DELIMETER));
}
```

I have a very simple question.  I want to run a loop inside the if statement to get all rows that satisfy the if condition.  Since there can be multiple rows with the same data1.getOpeningBankReference(). How would I do that?

For example in data1 there are 100 rows. I want that once it enters the if statement, it will give me all 5 rows as results (assuming there are 5 rows with the same OpeningBankRef) where data.getOpeningBankReference().equals(data1.getOpeningBankReference()) and then exit the if statement.

Comment: Not sure what you need but, recursion?

Comment: @YaWang I have two sets of data which will have different number of rows. So i need a loop inside if condition to run for the rows where ever if condition is satisfying i.e data.getOpeningBankReference().equals(data1.getOpeningBankReference())   So lets awesome in through if condition its clear data1.openref is X so i want all the rows with X then exit the if loop

Comment: @Sam - please edit your original post with more information. The code sample  and problem description you've provided is not enough to tell what you need.

Comment: "if loop" is a contradiction. An `if` statement is not a *loop*.

Comment: its a loop not a statement. Bad edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need your for outside the if and another inside. So you can compare all the rows with your data.getOpeningBankReference()

```
for (Row row: rows) {
   HasbroIssuanceDateData data1 = extractedDateData.get(row);

   if (data.getOpeningBankReference().equals(data1.getOpeningBankReference())) {
     for (Row anotherRow: anotherRows) {
          //here you have all the rows you need.
     }
   }
```

}

Comment: That wont help as it will result in index out of bound because there will different number of rows in two set of data

Comment: You cant get a index out of bound, it uses a foreach. There is no iterator.